# Modify battery percentage on real Android device

Tags: android, adb, battery

I have a rooted Galaxy S6 and I want to modify the battery percentage of the device for test purposes. I want that Android 'thinks' it has X percent battery...
I have already found that the percentage is stored at:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity
```

But when I try to modify the file, it says:

```
tmp-mksh: can't create capacity: Permission denied
```

Even if I try as root...
Is there some way to modify the percentage of the battery?

EDIT: I tried this too:

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Users\Valentino>adb root
adbd cannot run as root in production builds

C:\Users\Valentino>adb shell
shell@zerolte:/ $ su
su
root@zerolte:/ # setenforce 0
setenforce 0
root@zerolte:/ # echo 45 >> /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity
echo 45 >> /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity
tmp-mksh: can't create /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity: Permission deni
ed
1|root@zerolte:/ #
```

It doesn't work either...

Comment: Not possible without a kernel hack. sysfs provides write-access only to a few structures, and this would certainly be read-only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use following command:

`adb shell dumpsys battery set level 30`

to reset the original battery level back, use:

`adb shell dumpsys battery reset`

Comment: Nice to test and see that it works. I'll accept this answer now, as it's the only that works and it's even a oneliner.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below commands which might help you.

```
adb root
adb shell
su
setenforce 0
echo 45 >> /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity
```

This will change the battery level to 45% and it worked fine for me. :)

Comment: Surely is the file capacity present in the location ?